# Unable to click on checkbox in selenium on this URL https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am using this portal to automate for a demo:

https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb

on this webpage: there is a check box of privacy policy that i am unable to click via script. i am able to find the xpath properly but using that xpath selenium is unable to find that element to be clickable.

**My xpath :**

```
WebElement checkBox = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='agree']")));
```

**Method used to click on this element:**

```
public void setPrivacyPolicy()
{
    checkBox.click();   
}
```

Running same test case with Test class by calling setPrivacyPolicy() method.

Error message i am getting on console :

**element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (721, 795)**

**Additional :** with another statement i am able to interact with same xpath to retrieve its current state as selected or not and able to get it, but element click is not working.

- i have used normal wait : not worked
- i have used explicit wait : not worked
- Thread.sleep(): Not worked [Not recommeneded )

Your suggestions are welcome to solve this problem!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried the code that you provided , I am able to click the checkbox every time